# Why is sklearn RandomForestClassifier root node different from the most important feature?

Tags: scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

How is feature importance calculated in `RandomForestClassifier` in scikit-learn?
Here's a reproducible code. I run the classifier once with criterion set to `gini` and once to `entropy`. For each of them, I print the feature importance and plot the tree.
In neither of the instances, the root tree is the same as the most important feature. Why is that?

```python
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
from IPython.display import Image, display
from subprocess import call
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_wine
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
wines = load_wine()
iris = load_iris()

    
def create_and_fit(clf,model_name):
    print(clf)
# define dataset
    X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, n_informative=3, n_redundant=5, random_state=seed)
#    X,y = iris.data; iris.target
#    X,y = wines.data, wines.target
    # fit the mode
    clf.fit(X, y)

    # get importance
    importance = clf.feature_importances_
    indices = np.argsort(importance)[::-1]
    
    for f in range(X.shape[1]):
        print("feature {}: ({})".format(indices[f], importance[indices[f]]))
    filename = model_name+model.criterion
    if model_name == 'forest_':
        print('forest')
        export_graphviz(clf.estimators_[0], out_file=filename+'.dot')
    else:
        export_graphviz(clf, out_file=filename+'.dot')
    f = 'tree_'+model.criterion+'.png'
    call(['dot', '-Tpng', filename+'.dot', '-o', filename+'.png', '-Gdpi=600'])


seed=0    
models = [
    RandomForestClassifier(criterion='gini',max_depth=5, random_state=seed),
    RandomForestClassifier(criterion='entropy',max_depth=5, random_state=seed),
]    
names =['forest_', 'forest_']

for name, model in zip(names, models):
    create_and_fit(model,name)
```

Here's the snippet to load the image:

```python
Image(filename = 'forest_gini'+'.png')
```

and for the entropy

```python
Image(filename = 'forest_entropy'+'.png')
```

This behaviour seems to only happen with ensembles not trees (I'm generalizing as I only tried on Random forest and Decision Tree).

Here's the snippet for decision trees

```python
models = [
    DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='gini',max_depth=5, random_state=seed),
    DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy',max_depth=5, random_state=seed)
]    
names =['tree_', 'tree_']

for name, model in zip(names, models):
    create_and_fit(model,name)
```

Here's the snippet to load the image:

```python
Image(filename = 'tree_gini'+'.png')
```

and for the entropy

```python
Image(filename = 'tree_entropy'+'.png')
```

Comment: You're only looking at the first split in the first tree; maybe the most important feature shows up as the first split in (many of) the other trees?  That isn't strictly necessary either; I suspect an XOR problem with a depth-2 tree would show the non-root splits as having the vast majority of the importance as measured by criterion gain.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer, which is related to `max_features` parameter in RandomForestClassifier. Here's scikit-learn documentation:

> max_features{“sqrt”, “log2”, None}, int or float,
> default=”sqrt”
>
> The number of features to consider when looking for
> the best split:
>
> If int, then consider max_features features at each split.
>
> If float, then max_features is a fraction and round(max_features *
> n_features) features are considered at each split.
>
> If “auto”, then max_features=sqrt(n_features).
>
> If “sqrt”, then max_features=sqrt(n_features).
>
> If “log2”, then max_features=log2(n_features).
>
> If None, then max_features=n_features.

Comment: Also add that you have to chose the best feature between a **random subset of features** at each step (or split). That's why you have different values at your root node.